# Global Low Level Keyboard Hook for Combinations

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-hook

i know how to do **"Global Low Level Keyboard Hook"** thanks to [this](http://Global%20Low%20Level%20Keyboard%20Hook%20CodeProject%20Sample) tutorial.

I also wanted to monitor combination keys or shortcuts,

what my idea was that i could have an array of flags that could represent up\down states of keys of my keyboard.

Simply when a falg is **SET or 1** the key is down and when it is **UNSET or 0** the key is up.

I can use this for combination keys\shortcuts. When one key is down, the hook will take me to a function in which i will handle the event. What i will to do is, check whether any other particular flag is set. If yes then this means two keys are pressed simultaneously, and thus i have my combination.

I can make this trick work.

What i am looking for is a better option. Is there any.

Comment: As Cody Gray pointed out in his answer, global hooks are very heavy handed.  Most anti-virus programs will immediately flag your app as spyware, so you'll have to manually add them to the AV program's white list every time you install.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that better option is the [`RegisterHotKey` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309.aspx).

Global hooks are a very heavy approach and should only be used where absolutely necessary. In this case, it sounds like not only is a global hook unnecessary, but actually more complicated to implement than responding to a simple [`WM_HOTKEY` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646279.aspx) automatically generated each time your desired key sequence(s) are pressed.

Since you're using .NET, you will need to P/Invoke the `RegisterHotKey` function.
The definition looks something like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);
```

The `WM_HOTKEY` message, which you can process by overriding the [`WndProc` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx) of your form (the one whose handle you specified when calling the `RegisterHotKey` function, corresponds to the following value:

```
const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x0312;
```

The other required values are all clearly provided in the linked documentation for the `RegisterHotKey` function. The docs are, of course, required reading; otherwise you'll miss important caveats.